# Return || item is a valid syntax?

Tags: javascript

I see someone wrote `Return || item` in Javascript, what does this mean in a hacky form of code?

https://youtu.be/RpQTPWvD6HA?t=38m47s

Comment: Poor video quality, it says `return !! userId`

Comment: @adeneo Ah, good catch - got me of guard|

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript (for the 'actual code')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return || item` is SyntaxError. Video is saying `!!` (logical not not), which converts value to boolean.